# Excel to SAS Date not working in SAS

Tags: sas

I Have a file from excel that is in a short date format, but when SAS reads it in, it turns it into numbers in the 4000 range...when I try and convert this to an excel date with the below formula, it turns the year into 2077...is there a formula to ensure that this date remains in the original format on the read in, or avoid it turning into this 4000 range that is not at all close to the 2017 and 2018 year that my file is starting in. Does that make sense?

```
data change_date;
    format   Completed_Date mmddyy8. ;
    set check;
    completed_date = date_completed;
    if 42005 => date_completed >=43466 and date_completed ^=. then 
       Completed_date = Date_Completed-21916; *commented out 12-21-17 Xalka 
       dates back to how they are expected;
run;
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you expecting from completed_date = date_completed, that just copies over the variable.

Comment: You should be using something more similar to:` if year(completed_date) in (2017:2018)` but it's not clear what the actual issue is here, what do you have and what do you want?

Comment: Yes, but this is a common question. I'll see if I can find the duplicate.

Comment: I've been googling this question and I am not finding a solution. :(

Comment: Show what you have in Excel and what you did  to try and convert it. There's nothing in your code that looks like a date conversion. Did you try just applying a format to the date? What did that look like? How did you try and get the year to assume you're doing it wrong. And deleting things makes me look like I'm talking to myself.

Comment: Ok sorry. I did a PROC import on an excel file that had date_completed as 07/14/17 and when read into sas it became a number in the 4200+ range. My dataset above was an attempt to turn it back to that original date from the excel file. My IF statement is not doing that right now. Is there a way to prevent SAS from doing that on the read in, or to convert that 4200+ number back to the original date that excel had? Sorry for all the confusion.

Comment: I must be making this more complicated. How do I turn the excel date into a sas date, is essentially all I'm trying to do....

Comment: How did you import the file, you still need to provide the information I asked for and please add it to the question, not the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is a duplicate question, but I can't find it.

This is usually caused by mixing character and date values in the same column. This made SAS import the data as a character variable and it results in the actual dates being copied as character versions of the integers that Excel uses to store dates.

Frequently this is caused by entries that look like dates but are really character strings in the Excel file. The best way to fix it is to fix the Excel file so that the column only contains dates.  Otherwise you just need to convert the strings to integers and adjust the values to account for the differences in index dates.

So if your values are in a SAS dataset named `HAVE` in the character variable `DATESTRING` then you could use this data step to create a new variable with an actual date value.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  if indexc(datestring,'-/') then date=input(datestring,anydtdte32.);
  else date = input(datestring,32.) + '01JAN1900'D -2;
  format date yymmdd10. ;
run;
```

The minus 2 is because of difference in whether to start numbering with 1 or 0 and because Excel thinks 1900 was a leap year.

Answer (score 0):

Excel and SAS have different default dates in back-end.
Day 0 in SAS is 1 January 1960 and Day 0 in Excel is 1 January 1900.
So, you will need to convert excel numeric date to sas date using the below formula.
SAS_date = Excel_date - 21916;

```
    data dateExample;
informat dt mmddyy8.;
set dates;
SAS_date = dates - 21916; 
dt=sas_Date;
format dt date9.;
run;
```